# Automatically resize form/controls according to each computer's resolution

Tags: vb6

I've created a program that is fully functional and I have sent it to some clients. Some of them have really old computers with really low resolution and they can't access it easily since the form and the controls are oversized for them. Is there an easy way for me to make it to automatically resize both form and controls according to the resolution?

As I've said in the title, this is for Visual Basic 6.0. Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: No. Unfortunately some of my Clients don't have Net Framework and they can't download it (Ships). My program needs to be independent from .NET and that's why i use VB 6.0

Comment: Unfortunately, I only know of a .NET solution, where you can grab the viewport size and the screen size and adjust accordingly. There might be something similar you can do in VB?

Answer (score 1):

You can store size and location of each control on the form, and move or resize controls according to your needs.

In the code below, I use "TabIndex" property as unique id for each control (I can't remember in my old VB6 memory if that's the right thing to do...).
I store the size of the form, and the size and location of each control in the Form_Load event.

```
Private lWidth As Long
Private lHeight As Long

Private Enum ePROPERTY
    ep_Top = 0
    ep_Left = 1
    ep_Width = 2
    ep_Height = 3
End Enum

Private aControlSize() As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim ctlTmp As Control

lWidth = Me.Width
lHeight = Me.Height

ReDim aControlSize(3, Form1.Controls.Count)

For Each ctlTmp In Form1.Controls
    aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Top) = ctlTmp.Top
    aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Left) = ctlTmp.Left
    aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Width) = ctlTmp.Width
    aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Height) = ctlTmp.Height
Next

End Sub
```

Then each time the form is resized (Form_resize event), you'll have to move or resize each control.
Some of them need to be anchored to the right or to the bottom (or both). Some need to be resized and moved. Others don't need nothing.

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()

Dim ctlTmp As Control

For Each ctlTmp In Form1.Controls

    Select Case LCase$(ctlTmp.Name)

        Case "text1"
            ' Text1 is anchored to the left and right borders of the form :
            ctlTmp.Width = Me.Width - (lWidth - aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Width))

        Case "command1"
            ' Command1 is anchored to the right border of the form :
            ctlTmp.Left = aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Left) - (lWidth - Me.Width)

        Case "check1"
            ' check1 is anchored to the bottom border of the form :
            ctlTmp.Top = aControlSize(ctlTmp.TabIndex, ep_Top) - (lHeight - Me.Height)

    End Select

Next

End Sub
```

Form loaded :

[image]

Form Resized :

[image]

Please be advised that my code is largely perfectible...

There's probably a more elegant solution that goes through overload each Control and to add properties/methods like the existing ones in dotnet.